# VISUAL DATAFLEX How can I get the exit code of Runprogram

Tags: dataflex

Im launching a DOS program using `Runprogram wait "command plus args"`  wich exits with 1 whenever an error happends and 0 when everything works as expected...

Problem is, I'm unable to catch that exit code.

- I have tryed using [ShellExecuteA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) but dataflex wont wait for it to close...
- I have also tryed to use `Chain Wait` without any possitive result.

I'm using VDF 18.2 my App is a desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer which is working like a charm. Seems to be that DataFlex has this "magic variable" called `strmark` which is cleaned and filled everytime I issue the command `Runprogram Wait ('program') ('args')`.

So at the end of the day we can do something like this:

```
Runprogram Wait ('program.exe') ('my args')
If strmark Showln ('Well, we have an error my friend... Exit code: ' + strmark )
Else ...
```

This works like a charm when the program itself has a problem or even if the user closes the Command prompt window.